# Scrollbar affecting the div width

Tags: html, css

I have a div with propertie overflow auto. How to make the content of this div horizontally aligned with and without the scrollbar displayed. The scrollbar is messing with the div width. I hope you understand.

Comment: Show us some code and we might be able to help

Comment: Here are simple examples:  http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/1053/
  http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/1054/

Comment: Do you want to simply hide the scrollbar? Do you want the container to expand to accommodate _all_ the content?

Comment: I want the content to be to edge of the div not depending if there is a scrollbar or not. You can see the difference on the two examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

source: [Div with horizontal scrolling only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443700/div-with-horizontal-scrolling-only)

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079187/how-to-calculate-the-width-of-the-scroll-bar

Comment: you mean the width change in function of the content size? all div are like that by default else it is not html and css anymore, you need javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow-y: overlay` instead.

```
.your-content{
   overflow-y: overlay;
}
```

NOTE::: **`overflow-y: overlay` has been deprecated.**

But this will make the scrollbar appear as an overlay without affecting the width of div or element.