# Horizontal scrollbar appears with overflow content on right but not on left?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position, absolute

I have an element with `position: absolute` in `body` with some part of it *to the left* from left side.

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blr_Oliver/wq73u9jn/)

```css
* {
  overflow: visible;
}

#test {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: -50px;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

I expect that horizontal scrollbar should appear allowing to scroll the document to the hidden part of the element, but it doesn't. So, I have some questions about the case:

1. Why it happens so, why scrollbar doesn't appear (it works fine with symmetric layout on the right side)?
2. Is it ever possible to make it appear and **scroll to the left** ?
3. Am I missing anything very basic about scrollbars?

Answer (score 6):

In order to have scrollbars appear, the parent element must have a set width.
For horizontal scrollbars using the property `overflow-x:scroll;` on the parent will make the scrollbar appear.

Sounds similar to this issue:
[Div with horizontal scrolling only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443700/div-with-horizontal-scrolling-only)

To try and answer your questions:

1. The scrollbar appears when you use `right: -50px` because the standard flow of a HTML document is left to right. The CSS pushed the #test div out and the browser is able to continuing rendering to the right. It may look like part of the div is outwith the body at this point but it is not.
   Everything visible on an HTML page must be within the body.
2. Using the CSS `display: rtl;` on a parent container or the body would make the scrollbars scroll left instead of right, however if you did this to the body the whole document would now work right to left, changing all positioning in the page. I'd suggest having a parent element with the CSS property `display: rtl;`.

```css
#parent {
  position: static;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  direction: rtl;
}

#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lime;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="test">
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course this means the `#parent` element is always fully visible. If this was not wanted then the alternative *is* to set the `direction:rtl;` but ensure any content you want displayed correctly is then in a wrapper div which has CSS `direction: ltr;` to resume normal flow:

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#allOtherContent {
  direction: ltr;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lime;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="allOtherContent"></div>
```

3. Scrollbars appear when elements within another element are too big to fit. For this to work the browser needs to know the exact size of the parent element to determine that the test element is too big, and therefore needs to scroll.

In my example the `#parent` has a width of `100px`, the same as the `#test` div, however the `#test` div has been pushed left `50px` relative to `#parent` and therefore the `#test` div now requires `150px` of space. The parent now has overflowing content and the CSS `overflow-x:scroll;` adds our horizontal scrollbar.

More on how overflow and scrollbars work can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow.

Hope that helps answer your questions.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Scrollbar is there, but no scrolling to the left

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow-x: scroll;` to the `#test` div will give you a horizontal scrollbar.

## **Working Fiddle**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish Vasily? Move the green div into view with a bottom scroll bar?

Answer (score 1):

You should be follow this css code

```
*{
  overflow: visible;
}
#test{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  left: -50px;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

Comment: Nope, it's basically the same I have

Comment: What browser do you use? Chrome / Firefox / IE9 all do not work.

Comment: I am using Chrome / Firefox.

Comment: Sorry Vaslily. It's my mistake. You asking me about horizontal scrollbar and I am answering you about vertical scrollbar. I updated my code.

Comment: For Horizontal scrollbar appears this is basic css structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the direction from left to right (default) to right to left in the scrollable div.

```
direction: rtl;
```

This behaviour is due to the [CSS direction property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/).

> The direction property in CSS sets the direction of of content flow within a block-level element. This applies to text, inline, and inline-block elements. It also sets the default alignment of text and the direction that table cells flow within a table row.

That is why it is working when the [negative value is in the right rather than the left](https://jsfiddle.net/wq73u9jn/3/) because the flow goes from left to right (ltr) and the negative right makes the scrollable area adapt.

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
  direction: rtl;
}

#test {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left:-50px;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Well, it's a trick that does show the scrollbar, but the target block here has no parts positioned outside of its container. I need scroll that shows element not fully contained inside the body.

Comment: Ok, so please check the edited solution and let me know if it fits better.

Comment: Same thing, #test is positioned partially outside of #container but both #test and #container are completely within body. There is nothing that is positioned outside of the `body` rectangle.

Comment: You can not scroll in the same container outside of itself.

Comment: Well, seems logical, but same thing with `right` works

Comment: Could you post a fiddle showing what you mean with "right works"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131354/discussion-between-vasily-liaskovsky-and-alvaro).